# How to create a list view that makes a window with information pop-up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im just starting out with android studio and ive run into this block with an app that im trying to build.

Ive created a list view with the names of COVID vaccines, I want to code in such a way that when the user clicks on a vaccine a window/new activity pops up that shows them all the info about the vaccine in the form of a table.

How can I do that?

This is the Coding I have so far:

```
package com.example.covid_vaccine;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listViewVaccines = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterVaccines = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.vaccineArray,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listViewVaccines.setAdapter(adapterVaccines);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add OnItemClickListener in your adapter class
If you are new to Android studio see this tutorial from youtube to add OnItemClickListener it may help you

https://youtu.be/bhhs4bwYyhc
Happy coding:)